# While calling the loadquery why we pass "%"

Tags: kotlin, android-sqlite

I have a id,title, discription saved in my sqlite database, so while loading i pass the loadquery("%") i am not understaning what this % means, i am providing you the function code.

```
// calling the loadquery
Loadquery("%")



fun Loadquery(title:String)
{

    var dbManager=DbManager(this)
    val projections= arrayOf("ID","Title","Description")// array of cols
    val selectionArgs= arrayOf(title)                   // array of rows
    val cursor=dbManager.Query(projections,"Title like ?",selectionArgs,"Title")
    list_notes.clear()
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {

        do{
            val ID=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"))
            val Title=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Title"))
            val Description=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Description"))

            list_notes.add(note(ID,Title,Description))

        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
    }

    var myNotesAdapter= myadapter(list_notes)
    lis.adapter=myNotesAdapter


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The **`%`** is a wild sequence, so the query will return all rows where the Title is anything.

If you passed **`a%`** then it would return all rows that start with a (or A as LIKE is case insensitive).

If you passed **`%a%`** then it would return all rows that have an a anywhere in the  in the title and so on.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - expression - The LIKE, GLOB, REGEXP, and MATCH operators](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) says :-

> The LIKE operator does a pattern matching comparison.
>
> The operand to
> the right of the LIKE operator contains the pattern and the left hand
> operand contains the string to match against the pattern.
>
> **A percent
> symbol ("%") in the LIKE pattern matches any sequence of zero or more
> characters in the string.**
>
> An underscore ("_") in the LIKE pattern
> matches any single character in the string. Any other character
> matches itself or its lower/upper case equivalent (i.e.
> case-insensitive matching).
>
> Important Note: SQLite only understands
> upper/lower case for ASCII characters by default. The LIKE operator is
> case sensitive by default for unicode characters that are beyond the
> ASCII range.